# How to get multidimensional array working in tableview

Tags: iphone, swift, xcode

I am creating an iOS Swift 3 app and in this app I have a tableview with data coming from an API. I want to display this data in the tableview but I want to do it grouped by firstname. I have managed to first group the data (see below) but xCode is complaining that XXX.

**This is the declaration of the sections:**

```
var sections = [String: [User]]()
```

**This is how I group the data:**

```
self.sections = Dictionary(grouping: self.contacts.filter({ !$0.firstname!.isEmpty })) {
                $0.firstname!.prefix(1).capitalized
            }
```

**This is my output:**

```
["D": [motto.User(id: Optional(1), firstname: Optional("Dan"), lastname: Optional("Meeler"), email: Optional("time@example.com"))], "M": [coiqo.User(id: Optional(3), firstname: Optional("Mia"), lastname: Optional("Kallas"), email: Optional("mia@ka.com"))]]
```

**This is the error I got:**

```
Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : [User]]' with an index of type 'Int'
```

**In this function for tableview:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return sections[section].count
    }
```

How can I get this array to work in a tableview?

**Update**

I just had to add this to dasblinkenlight answer and it worked!

```
if(groupKeys.count > 0) {
            return sections[groupKeys[section]]!.count
        } else {
            return sections.count
        }
```

Comment: `let key = sections.keys.sorted()[section]; return sections[key].count`?

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work. I got "Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range"

Comment: Which line? The one I suggest? I think you have an issue elsewhere. Also, I'd do `var array = [[String:[User]]](); for (_, aKey) in keys.enumerated() { array.append([aKey:dict[aKey]!])}`  and I'd use that `array` to populate your tableView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `self.sections` is `Dictionary`, and dictionaries are unordered.

Once you've made user groups from API results, make a separate array composed of group keys:

```
let groupKeys : [String] = Array(self.sections.keys)
```

Sort that array in the way that you wish your sections to appear (alphabetical, reverse alphabetical, natural, etc.)

Now you can write your function like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return sections[groupKeys[section]].count
}
```

Comment: I unfortunately get Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range

Comment: @JonathanClark I didn't check that, but I think that your "Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range" is elsewhere, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` for instance, because setting a correct `numberOfRowsInSection` means also to adapt the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` for it.

Comment: No I get it in the numberOfRowsInSection function. Or at least xcode points on that line.